# recursive array function in c

Tags: arrays, c, recursion

Im trying to figure out why the output of this recursive function is

> ```
> -25,25,5
> ```

Why is it not `-11` since it will be `j[3] - j[2] - j[1] - j[0] + 16`?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NUM 4
double rec(const double j[], size_t i);

int main(void) {
    double h;
    double g[NUM] = { 4.75,9,13.25 };
    h = rec(g, NUM);
    printf("%.2f , %.2f, %.2f", h, fabs(h), sqrt(fabs(h)));
}
double rec(const double j[], size_t i) {
    if (i == 1)
    {
        return j[0] + 16;
    }
    else
    {
        return j[i - 1] - rec(j, i - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `NUM` is **4** but your array only has **3** elements initialized.

Comment: @alex01011 Omitted initializers default to `0`.

Comment: `0 - (13.25 - (9 - (4.75 + 16))) == -25`.

Comment: j[3] will be equal 0. it doesn't really matter. if i change NUM to 3, its just that instead of -25, h will be 25. but my question is why is it 25

Comment: @Siguza omg thank you sooooooooo much !!!!!!

Comment: Stepping through the code in a debugger is a simple way to see what's happening.

Comment: What is the function supposed to do?

Comment: i have no idea to be honest... this is just part of an exam paper where i have to write out the output without a computer, all through manual calculation